# img not displaying in .php file

Tags: php, html, image

I have a very basic webpage that for some reason image will not appear on the webpage. When I use a full URL linking to an external site the image appears fine but I cannot link to images I'm hosting locally and I have no idea why. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/style.css">
</header>

<body>
    <?php require_once 'common/header.php' ?>

    <div class="container">

        <img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1410/M6SidingSpringLigustri.jpg" alt="Test 1" height="200" width="300">
        <img src="1.png" height="200" width="300">
        <img src="common/2.png" height="200" width="300">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?!?

Comment: Either the path is wrong or something with your server is improperly configured. Are you using any anti-leeching scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Image files don't display inside php files?  What you have there is an html source file that has an image tag with a source value.

There are a few reasons why an image won't display which could be an invalid image, file not existing etc.  Try copy the src into the url of your browser and it should display the picture.

If the picture does not display, it will give you a good idea as to why not.

Answer (score 0):

According to your HTML, the image `1.png` has to be in the same folder as the HTML page and `2.png` has to be inside the `common` folder which in turn has to be in the same folder as the HTML page.

```
|_index.html
|_1.png
|_common
        |_2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you want to display the NASA pic use this:

```
https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1410/M6SidingSpringLigustri.jpg
```

I loaded the URL and it loaded an URL using SSL.